# select column from an array based on id

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller, eloquent, laravel-8

I want to filter through this array `$bank_totals` and select a value of amount only.

$bank_totals = $bank_totals->bank_balances();

```
"id" => 1
    "bank" => "KCB"
    "amount" => 7622.0
  ]
  1 => array:3 [
    "id" => 2
    "bank" => "I & M Bank"
    "amount" => 25000.0
```

am getting the id from user input $data['id']; I want when the $data['id'] = 2 example the value shown is 25000
$data = request()->all();
$bank_totals = $bank_totals->bank_balances();
(to appear here)

here is my bank_balances method

```
class TransactionsRepository
{
        public function bank_balances(){
            $banks_data = Bank::all();
            $banks_totals = [];

            foreach ($banks_data as $bank){
                $totals = (BankingTransactions::where('bank_id', $bank->id)->sum('amount')) -
                    ((PettyCash::where('bank_id', $bank->id)->sum('amount')) + ((PayDoctor::where('bank_id', $bank->id)
                            ->sum('total_paid'))));
               array_push($banks_totals,
                    [
                        'id'=>$bank->id,
                        'bank'=>$bank->name,
                        'amount'=>$totals,
                    ]);
            }
            return $banks_totals;
        }
}
```

Comment: Please share content of your `bank_balances()` method

Comment: shared @SemihSAHIN in the code

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `bank_balances` method with this:

```
public function bank_balances($id = null) {
    $banks_data = Bank::all();
    $banks_totals = [];
    if (is_null($id)) {
        foreach ($banks_data as $bank) {
            $totals = (BankingTransactions::where('bank_id', $bank->id)->sum('amount')) -
                ((PettyCash::where('bank_id', $bank->id)->sum('amount')) + ((PayDoctor::where('bank_id', $bank->id)
                    ->sum('total_paid'))));
            array_push(
                $banks_totals,
                [
                    'id' => $bank->id,
                    'bank' => $bank->name,
                    'amount' => $totals,
                ]
            );
        }
        return $banks_totals;
    } else {
        return (BankingTransactions::where('bank_id', $id)->sum('amount')) -
            ((PettyCash::where('bank_id', $id)->sum('amount')) + ((PayDoctor::where('bank_id', $id)
            ->sum('total_paid'))));
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
$bank_totals = $bank_totals->bank_balances($data['id']);
```